# Cannot install Haskell CUDA on 64bit Linux

Tags: linux, haskell, cuda, cabal

I'm having trouble installing/building haskell-cuda using cabal on 64bit Arch Linux. As far as I'm aware I have all the prerequisites (ie, cuda runtime libraries, nvcc compiler etc).

The error I get is as follows:

```
cabal install cuda
[all tests pass]
Building cuda-0.5.1.1...
Preprocessing library cuda-0.5.1.1...
[ 1 of 27] Compiling Foreign.CUDA.Driver.Error ( dist/build/Foreign/CUDA/Driver/Error.hs, dist/build/Foreign/CUDA/Driver/Error.o )
[ 2 of 27] Compiling Foreign.CUDA.Internal.Offsets ( dist/build/Foreign/CUDA/Internal/Offsets.hs, dist/build/Foreign/CUDA/Internal/Offsets.o )
[ 3 of 27] Compiling Foreign.CUDA.Internal.C2HS ( Foreign/CUDA/Internal/C2HS.hs, dist/build/Foreign/CUDA/Internal/C2HS.o )
[ 4 of 27] Compiling Foreign.CUDA.Driver.Utils ( dist/build/Foreign/CUDA/Driver/Utils.hs, dist/build/Foreign/CUDA/Driver/Utils.o )

Foreign/CUDA/Driver/Utils.chs:35:23:
    Illegal type signature: `IO (Status, Int) cuDriverGetVersion'
      Perhaps you intended to use -XScopedTypeVariables
    In a pattern type-signature
Failed to install cuda-0.5.1.1
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
cuda-0.5.1.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

From what I understand this is an error with the source on Hackage, however I might have misunderstood, and it's an error with my machine. Either way, how should I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so it seems (based on [this](https://github.com/tmcdonell/cuda/issues/7)) that the problem was actually a fault with the c2hs program, in version 0.16.6

The solution was to downgrade to version 0.16.5, and from there, try again to install CUDA.

```
cabal install c2hs-0.16.5
cabal install cuda
```

After downgrading, installation went perfectly!